# How to deploy corda spring boot APIs?

Tags: corda

I have a corda network running on a VM on Azure with two parties and a notary. I would like to deploy the spring boot APIs, but not sure how to do that and where.

Any link to documentations or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to deploy it anywhere you want - in the same VM of your Corda node or another one. The only thing you need to take care of is the configuration of RPC connection in the `node.conf`, where you set the RPC settings and users, like this example:

```
rpcSettings {
    useSsl = false
    standAloneBroker = false
    address = "my-corda-node:10003"
    adminAddress = "my-corda-node:10004"
}
rpcUsers = [
    { username=user1, password=test, permissions=[] }
]
```

More information [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/clientrpc.html).

If you don't know how to deploy Spring Boot in general, the official documentation of Spring Boot is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html).

Remember to also properly set the network configurations in your Azure infrastructure in order to allow RPC traffic between the client and the node.